# Stop docker container from playwright test

Tags: docker, shell, playwright

How to stop docker container running on remote server from playwright test?

I am trying:

function:

```
import { exec } from "child_process";

export function stopContainer(containerId: number) {

  // SSH connection and command
  const sshCommand = `sshpass -p "${password}" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${remoteUser}@${remoteHost} "cd /container${containerId} && docker-compose down -d"`;

  // Execute the SSH command
  exec(sshCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
      return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
      console.error(`SSH Error: ${stderr}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Result of exec: ${stdout}`);
  });
}
```

playwright test:

```
test.beforeAll(async () => {
  console.log("Before tests");
  stopContainer(309);
});

test(`Test`, async ({}) => {

  console.log("In test.");
});
```

It seems that exec command is not executed/ nothing happend, no error logged.
Playwright is running on docker image.

Comment: execSync(sshCommand); fixed the issues